# Move assignable class containing vector<unique_ptr<T>>

Tags: c++, move-semantics, rvalue-reference

The class Foo has an rvalue reference constructor that moves the contained vector of `unique_ptr`s so why does the following code give the following error, both with or without the `std::move` on the `Foo()` in `main`?

```
error C2280: 'std::unique_ptr<SomeThing,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>>::operator =(const std::unique_ptr<_Ty,std::default_delete<_Ty>> &)' : attempting to reference a deleted function
```

```
class Foo{
public:
    Foo(){

    }
    Foo(Foo&& other) :
        m_bar(std::move(other.m_bar))
    {};

    std::vector<std::unique_ptr<SomeThing>> m_bar;
};

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    Foo f;
    f = std::move(Foo());
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

This:

```
 f = std::move(Foo());
```

doesn't call the move constructor. It calls the move assignment operator. Furthermore, it's redundant, since `Foo()` is already an rvalue so that's equivalent to:

```
f = Foo();
```

Since you declared a move constructor, the move assignment operator isn't declared - so there isn't one. So you either have to provide one:

```
Foo& operator=(Foo&& other) {
    m_bar = std::move(other.m_bar);
    return *this;
}
```

Or, since all your members implement move operations themselves, you could just delete your move constructor and rely on the compiler-generated implicit move constructor and move assignment.

Comment: Removal of the move constructor and/or the std::move() on Foo() does not seem to stop the compile error.

Comment: Definition of the move assignment operator with the addition of return *this. Does work.

Comment: @EdwardJBrown: [Works on gcc](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/34891faacd262655)

Comment: @AndyG Doesn't seem to work in vs2013 msvc, just used your exact code and got the same error. Probably a Microsoft bug. Thanks anyway

Comment: @EdwardJBrown: Depending on your actual code (and not this toy problem), you may be implicitly deleting the move constructor/assignment by defining a copy constructor/assignment

Comment: @AndyG http://pastebin.com/12qLJq3e Is the relevant code, removal of the assignment definition results in the error above when setting an array element = to an instance of OctreeNode.