# How do I move a vector of objects that contain a unique_ptr as a member?

Tags: c++, move, stdvector, unique-ptr

I have a function that returns an `std::vector` of a class that contains a `std::unique_ptr` as member. I need to store this vector object on the heap so I can pass it through a C-style DLL interface.

See the following code sample:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <memory>
#include <vector>

// I have control over the following two classes
class SomeBigClassWithManyMembers { };

class MyClass
{
    std::unique_ptr<SomeBigClassWithManyMembers> up;

public:
    static const std::vector<MyClass> GetMany()
    {
        // imagine this does lots of work
        return std::vector<MyClass>(50);
    }

    // following code is suggested in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31430533/move-assignable-class-containing-vectorunique-ptrt but doesn't help
    /*
    MyClass() { }
    MyClass(MyClass&& other): up{std::move(other.up)} { }
    MyClass& operator=(MyClass&& other)
    {
        up = std::move(other.up);
        return *this;
    }
    */
};

// Imagine that I can't change this C-style code - it's a fixed interface provided by someone else
struct NastyCStyleStruct
{
    void* v;
};
void NastyCStyleInterface(NastyCStyleStruct s) { printf("%u", (unsigned int)((std::vector<MyClass>*)s.v)->size()); }

int main()
{
    NastyCStyleStruct s;
    s.v = new std::vector<MyClass>(std::move(MyClass::GetMany()));
    NastyCStyleInterface(s);
    return 0;
}
```

Note that in my actual code, the vector needs to outlive the function in which it is created (because this is being done in a DLL), so writing

```
auto vec = MyClass::GetMany();
s.v = &vec;
```

would **not** suffice. The vector must be stored on the heap.

The trouble here is that the code seems to try to use the (non-existent) copy constructor of `MyClass`. I can't understand why the copy constructor is being invoked, because I am explicitly asking for move semantics with `std::move`. Not even initialising `s.v` to a fresh `new std::vector` of the appropriate size and calling the three-argument version of `std::move` works.

Errors from g++:

```
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:64:0,
                 from stackq.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Construct(_T1*, _Args&& ...) [with _T1 = MyClass; _Args = {const MyClass&}]’:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:83:18:   required from ‘static _ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy<_TrivialValueTypes>::__uninit_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MyClass*, std::vector<MyClass> >; _ForwardIterator = MyClass*; bool _TrivialValueTypes = false]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:134:15:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::uninitialized_copy(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MyClass*, std::vector<MyClass> >; _ForwardIterator = MyClass*]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_uninitialized.h:289:37:   required from ‘_ForwardIterator std::__uninitialized_copy_a(_InputIterator, _InputIterator, _ForwardIterator, std::allocator<_Tp>&) [with _InputIterator = __gnu_cxx::__normal_iterator<const MyClass*, std::vector<MyClass> >; _ForwardIterator = MyClass*; _Tp = MyClass]’
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_vector.h:331:31:   required from ‘std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>::vector(const std::vector<_Tp, _Alloc>&) [with _Tp = MyClass; _Alloc = std::allocator<MyClass>]’
stackq.cpp:43:65:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/stl_construct.h:75:7: error: use of deleted function ‘MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)’
     { ::new(static_cast<void*>(__p)) _T1(std::forward<_Args>(__args)...); }
       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
stackq.cpp:10:7: note: ‘MyClass::MyClass(const MyClass&)’ is implicitly deleted because the default definition would be ill-formed:
 class MyClass
       ^~~~~~~
stackq.cpp:10:7: error: use of deleted function ‘std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>::unique_ptr(const std::unique_ptr<_Tp, _Dp>&) [with _Tp = SomeBigClassWithManyMembers; _Dp = std::default_delete<SomeBigClassWithManyMembers>]’
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7/memory:80:0,
                 from stackq.cpp:4:
/usr/include/c++/7/bits/unique_ptr.h:388:7: note: declared here
       unique_ptr(const unique_ptr&) = delete;
       ^~~~~~~~~~
```

How can I repair this code so that the vector object itself is stored on the heap?

Comment: The copy constructor is being invoked because `GetMany` is defined to return a `const std::vector`, not a `std::vector`, so `std::move` can't actually make it into a r-value; moving from it would violate the `const`-ness, so copying is the only option. Odds are you don't need the `vector` on the heap (though it might make the code easier), you just need to stop inhibiting copy elision/move semantics.

Comment: Ah yes, silly me for not noticing that! Removing the `const` on `GetMany` now allows the code to compile.

Comment: @MarekR: The OP's code appears to be intended to work with a weird C-like interface, so they may not have much of a choice.

Comment: @ShadowRanger I'm aware of that, but passing pointer to `std::vector` to C API is defiantly wrong (I don't see scenario were it could be correct). Most probably he needed value returned by `std::vector::data`. Note also that he is a newbie, so this must be result of permutative-programing.

Comment: In fact I'm suspecting [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: @MarekR: In this case the code resides in a Windows DLL which is called from another language. The `std::vector` instances reside in the address space of the other language's runtime process. Of course there would be problems if I was trying to pass these `std::vector`s to other binaries, since they probably have a different definition for `std::vector`. But in this case that is not an issue. The other language treats the pointers as opaque integers.

Comment: @AlanThomas It would be better if you edit your question and provide more context. Start from readying about XY problem. If this is a bridge to other language state that clearly and describe what bridging technique you are using (for example python has at least to ways). As you can see with current contents of question you have little chance to receive useful answer - question is quite old and the only provided answer apparently doesn't help you.

Comment: I intentionally omitted to mention the other language, as I don't have time or resources to alter the interop aspect of the problem. It is fixed in place and I must work within its constraints. I was afraid of getting answers like "ah yes, since you're using Python/Node.js/VB6/... here is a better way to achieve this outcome", which would be useless to me in these circumstances. All that mattered is that a pointer had to be conveyed, and that is the problem I was needing to solve. As it stands, my question has been answered (I just marked it as such), so I am satisfied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that `GetMany` is defined to return a `const std::vector`. Even though it's returning by value, so there's no risk of unwanted side-effects if you mutate the result, the compiler still enforces the type (`auto` just copied the exact return type of the function after all), making it impossible to move from it. So instead of cheaply copying a few pointer/`size_t`-sized values (to the `vector` contents, size and capacity), it had to do a full copy construction, including copy constructing all the values stored in the original `vector`. That fails due to the `unique_ptr` member in the stored instances.

Simply dropping the `const` from the return type should allow `std::move`/`vector`'s move constructor to do their job, allowing the ultra-cheap extraction of the contents of the `vector` returned by `GetMany` with no copies (or even moves) of any instance of `MyClass`.